# Extract the name of the folder housing an email

Tags: powershell, outlook, extract, metadata, office-automation

I am trying to extract email metadata from messages in an Outlook Exchange account.  I derive various metadata as described [here](https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/outlook-email/#Ideas_for_Analyzing_Outlook_Emails), but I can't get the name of the folder where the email has been stored.

What I have so far:

```
Clear-Host
$outlook = New-Object -Com Outlook.Application
$mapi = $outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
$mailboxRoot = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).Parent
$walkFolderScriptBlock = {
    param(
        $currentFolder
    )
    foreach ($item in $currentFolder.Folders) {
                $item.Items
                }
            }

$Email = & $walkFolderScriptBlock $mailboxRoot
$Results = $Email | Select ConversationTopic, ReceivedTime;
$Results | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\2024-01-25EmailTesting.csv
```

I tried variants of the word "folder" following the word "Select". It returns an empty column.

*Update* - @mhu has made a breakthrough and gotten the names of folders.  When I run their script, I see folders like "Delete" and "Inbox".  Which is a major step forward, but am wondering if I could also get the subfolders under "Inbox" (i.e. "Accessibility Committee" and "Advisory").

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the parent name property like this:

(and you don't need the script block, unless you want to recursively process the folders)

```
$results     = @()
$outlook     = New-Object -Com "Outlook.Application"
$mapi        = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$mailboxRoot = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).Parent
$folders     = $mailboxRoot.Folders | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Items"
foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
    $results += $folder | 
        Where-Object { $_.Class -eq 43 } | 
        Select-Object -Property "ConversationTopic", "ReceivedTime", @{ "Label" = "Folder"; "Expression" = { $_.Parent.Name } }
}
$results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\email.csv"
```

Example output:

```
ConversationTopic                                    ReceivedTime        Folder
-----------------                                    ------------        ------
This week at Humble: Mega Man franchise pack & more! 10/02/2024 16:16:58 Test
```

Advanced example for processing nested folders:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest"
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

function Get-MailFromOutlookFolder
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param 
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Object] $ParentFolder
    )

    $items = @()

    foreach ($folder in $ParentFolder.Folders)
    {
        foreach ($item in ($folder | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Items"))
        { 
            if ($item.Class -eq 43)
            {
                # process email
                $items += $item | Select-Object -Property "ConversationTopic", "ReceivedTime", @{ "Label" = "Folder"; "Expression" = { $_.Parent.Name } }
            }
        }

        # process (sub)folder items
        $items += Get-MailFromOutlookFolder -ParentFolder $folder
    }

    return $items    
}

$outlook     = New-Object -Com "Outlook.Application"
$mapi        = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$mapi.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).Parent

$results = Get-MailFromOutlookFolder -ParentFolder $mailboxRoot
$results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\email.csv"
```

Comment: I'm getting a list of folders with nothing in them.  The "ConversationTopic" and "ReceivedTime" columns are blank.

Comment: Check the contents of `$email`  (`$email | Select-Object -Property "*"`). Which properties are available to you?

Comment: Under email properties are: Application, Class, Session, Parent, Count, RawTable, and IncludeRecurrences.  Thank you for helping!

Comment: Sorry, I tested it with only 1 folder. Updated the answer for multiple folders

Comment: I did your `Select-Object -Property "*"` on the original script and it was very helpful - no property called "folder", but good to know what the properties are.

Comment: That worked!!  It gives me the folders, but not the subfolders.  Is there any chance it can get subfolders too?

Comment: It could you are seeing other item types (non-email). Added an email filter to the answer

Comment: Added advanced example for nested folders

Answer (score 0):

Use `MailItem.Parent.Name`. But since you are processing items from a particular folder, you already know what the parent folder is - just use `$item.Name`

Comment: Hi @Dmitry Streblechenko - thank you for helping.  I'm a novice at PowerShell - can you tell me know exactly where the $item.Name is supposed to go in the script?

Comment: hi again, I substituted `$item.Items` in the above script with `$item.Folders` and then substituted `ConversationTopic` with `Name` and hooray - I've got a list of folders.  But how to marry the items with the folders?

Comment: Tried making an empty array (`$item = @()`) then including `item.Items` and `item.Folders` in the loop.  It just gave me an empty `Name` column again

Comment: `item.Items.Count` or `item.Folders.Count`. BTW, the item variable really needs to be named `folder`

Comment: Hi @Dmitry Streblechenko Would you be willing to post your full code?  I'm not sure how to integrate your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Each item in Outlook has the `Parent` property which stands for the folder where the items is located. I am not sure whether the property call will work correctly in PS, but let's try the following:

```
Clear-Host
$outlook = New-Object -Com Outlook.Application
$mapi = $outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
$mailboxRoot = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).Parent
$walkFolderScriptBlock = {
    param(
        $currentFolder
    )
    foreach ($item in $currentFolder.Folders) {
                $item.Items
                }
            }

$Email = & $walkFolderScriptBlock $mailboxRoot
$Results = $Email | Select ConversationTopic, ReceivedTime, Parent.Name;
$Results | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\2024-01-25EmailTesting.csv
```

Also you may check the parent folder name in the loop, but I don't see how it can help in the loop:

```
Clear-Host
$outlook = New-Object -Com Outlook.Application
$mapi = $outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
$mailboxRoot = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).Parent
$walkFolderScriptBlock = {
    param(
        $currentFolder
    )
    foreach ($item in $currentFolder.Folders) {
                Write-Host $item.Name
                $item.Items
                }
            }

$Email = & $walkFolderScriptBlock $mailboxRoot
$Results = $Email | Select ConversationTopic, ReceivedTime;
$Results | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\2024-01-25EmailTesting.csv
```

Comment: Hi @Eugene Astafiev!  thank you for your code.  I wasn't able to get it to work though - it produced empty values under the "Parent.Name" column in the csv.

Comment: Do you see the folder name printed in the loop?

Comment: It produced an error "Ampersand character not allowed".  I replaced the ampersand with `$` and got folder names. Still no output in csv though.